# Meteor css and javascript files loading best practice

Tags: javascript, meteor, load-order

**TL,DR:** *How to load css and javascript files independent of Meteor assumptions about alphabetical order (which is far from how it works in practice.)*

Stackoverflow tells me this question might be subjective but I hope not.

Meteor loads files based on alphabetical order (and other rules.)
So to force it to load the CSS and JS files in the order I wanted, I had to start the fiels with numbers that indicate the load order. If I have `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`, Meteor will load `bootstrap.js` before `jquery.js`. But bootstrap depends on jquery so jquery must be loaded first.

In order to solve this, the options are:
1. Put the files in the `public` directory and manually load them. But this didn't work as Meteor appears to be sending the files with `text/html` MIME type.
2. Create a Meteor package and specify the load order from there. I find this like hitting a fly with a hammer just for loading CSS and Javascript.
3. Put a number before every file. In the previous example, to load jquery before bootstrap, rename the fiels to `1.jquery.js` and `2.bootstrap.js` This works and is tedious but at least I get to load the files the way I want them to.

I am new to Meteor so I am wondering if there are recommended best practices concerning this. I was thinking of using AMD for javascript but that's limited to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an interesting question and this is probably one of the pitfalls of making a Meteor app.

You've mentioned all of the usable solutions such as creating an explicit package or renaming the files.

The best way I would think is to use the atmosphere packages. For example if you add bootstrap, jquery is a dependency of it so it will always load first. Most js libraries that involve load order are typically on atmosphere.

The other best way if there's no atmosphere package, though i'm not sure I would say is tedious is to put a number in front of the js file to indicate load order.

One thing is when you use the `/public` folder the files map to `/`, so you can load the js file yourself manually in the order you would want (in the root html file using /public. Meteor returns the text/html MIME type as its version of a 404 file not found error. This method is a bit troublesome though because the files are seperated in production and can cause trouble if one or the other dont load.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am trying to stick to the Meteor way as much as possible so for now, I went with the file numbering. And a second issue cropped up. When I added `iron:router`, it is loading the templates before the javascript files that the templates depend on and now I feel as if I have to monkey patch every time to get something to work. I am going to try the `/public` folder suggestion and I hope it solves the problem with IronRouter.

Comment: And as for going with atmosphere, I shall see if all the packages I need are there.

Comment: I ended up sticking to the numbering system. Moving the files to the `/public` folder didn't solve the problem (but the 404 did disappear.) As for the IronRouter problem, I moved the code into `Template.myTemplate.rendered` and it is now working. Thanks :-)